# How to make same fields not appear twice in SQL self join?

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to do a self-join in a tale and make a pair of customers but i do not want the same pair to appear twice i am using this code

```
  SELECT DISTINCT A.customer_num AS ' num1' 
                , B.customer_num AS 'num2' 
                , A.customer_name AS 'name1' 
                , B.customer_name AS 'name2' 
                , A.city AS 'city' 
             FROM tbl_customer A 
                , tbl_customer B
            WHERE A.customer_num <> B.customer_num
              AND A.city = B.city  ;
```

it gives me the records but the pair gets repeated and this is what result i get [My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbidb.jpg) such as 1 and 6th pair are the same in what i get
and i'm using MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `where` condition on a self-join is *symmetric* (i.e. `A.customer_num <> B.customer_num`) each pair will appear twice in the output. It does not matter which record is `A` or `B`, so switching the condition to *asymmetric* will fix the problem.

While you are at it, switch to using ANSI joins; you no longer need `DISTINCT`, too:

```
SELECT
    A.customer_num AS 'num1'
,   B.customer_num AS 'num2'
,   A.customer_name AS 'name1'
,   B.customer_name AS 'name2' ,
A.city AS 'city' 
FROM tbl_customer A -- It does not matter if you use < or > below
JOIN tbl_customer B ON A.customer_num > B.customer_num AND A.city = B.city
```

Comment: do i still need DISTINCT ? or not @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @HarryKashyap No, you should be able to drop `DISTINCT` clause.